# Database query failed. Error received from database was #144:

Tags: mysql, repair

```
Database query failed. Error received from database was #144: Table 'dbname.mantis_bug_file_table' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed for the query: SELECT bug_id, COUNT(bug_id) AS attachments
FROM mantis_bug_file_table
GROUP BY bug_id.
```

How to avoid above issue. Many times I got this error after repair table. If I repair table after loading the page it's says "#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stop MySQL process first.Go to your data folder and try running `myisamchk -r <table_name>`.  If it is not work then try with `myisamchk -r -v -f <table_name>.`

Comment: Where I have to run this myisamchk -r <table_name>.

Comment: see here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-repair-corrupted-mysql-tables-using-myisamchk/